# Change SSL encryption to 128 bit from 256 bit

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have bought SSL using Godaddy and running nginx over an ubuntu machine. I have came to know that I am using 256 bit encryption with my SSL certificate. I want to downgrade it to 128 bit. How is it possible? Do I need to make change only in nginx for that or in godaddy also? What changes could be required to make this switch.

I am trying to do this for this website = https://www.winni.in

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: To increase speed of website initial load. Read in several blogs that speed of 128 bit encryption is better than 256 bit and security offered by 128 bit encryption is more than enough for general use cases

Answer (score 1):

Your key is 2048 bits. 
It is signed at 256 bits.

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.winni.in

In Nginx you can set the preferred cipher suite with ssl_ciphers so with that, you could enforce only 128 bit encryption.

Is it a good idea? I don't think so. You probably get more of a speed boost by not sending the CA certificate which is already in the browsers' trust store.

And you don't have session resumption enabled, no HSTS, no OCSP stapling.

You have bigger fish to fry.